# How to fix longtable and bigfoot LaTeX packages conflict?

Tags: latex, longtable

When I compile a single *.tex file on my local machine, it seems like the `longtable` and `bigfoot` packages conflict resulting in wrong "sticking" of the table header on the next page.
Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ | c | c | }
\hline
\textbf{First column}  & \textbf{Second column}     \\ \hline
\endhead
test & test \\ \hline
...
test & test \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

First page is correct, while all subsequent pages are wrong: they have the header row detached from the table.

The weird thing is when I comment `\usepackage{bigfoot}` row, it works.

From my investigation:

- it works on other machines with both `pdflatex` and `latex`;
- it fails on my computer with both `pdflatex` and `latex`.

I have most of `texlive-*` packages installed in Ubuntu, and I have found that `bigfoot` loads the following during compilation:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bigfoot/bigfoot.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ncctools/manyfoot.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ncctools/nccfoots.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bigfoot/suffix.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bigfoot/perpage.sty
```

I need to use `bigfoot` package, as it's used in the project I'm working with, but I want to fix the bug with `longtable`. Any ideas?

Comment: Good question. I would propose to migrate it to [tex.stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have duplicated the question [there](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263958/how-to-fix-longtable-and-bigfoot-latex-packages-conflict).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kindly [answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263958/how-to-fix-longtable-and-bigfoot-latex-packages-conflict) by egreg user on tex.stackexchange.com, the problem is in outdated bigfoot package. 
The problematic package has shown: `Package: bigfoot 2006/07/15 1.25 makes footnotes work`

What I did to fix that was:

1. Downloaded latest `bigfoot` package (zip archive) from CTAN
2. Unpacked it and ran `tex bigfoot.ins` to generate `bigfoot.sty`;
3. Moved it to the directory where it was spotted when compiling my pdf:
   `sudo cp bigfoot.sty /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bigfoot/`;
4. Updated some latex caches: `sudo mktexlsr`.

With `bigfoot.sty 2015/08/30 2.1 makes footnotes work` it works fine.